# Finding the geometric sum of this recurrence

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I'm having trouble with evaluating geometric sequences that look like this:

$Cn\sum_{i=0}^{\log_3n} (5/3)^i$

where $n$ is the number of operations, and $Cn$ just represents $n$ times some constant $C$.
I'm trying to get the big $O$ of this, but I'm not quite sure.

Is it equal to $O(n^{log_35})$?

Also, if it was $(3/5)^i$ instead, would it just be $O(1)$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
T(n)
&=Cn\sum_{i=0}^{\log_3n} (5/3)^i\\
&=Cn\frac{(5/3)^{1+\log_3(n)}-1}{5/3-1}\\
&=\frac 32Cn((5/3)^{1+\log_3(n)}-1)\\
&\sim\frac 52Cn\left(\frac 53\right)^{\log_3(n)}\\
&=\frac 52C5^{\log_3(n)}\\
&=\frac 52C5^{\log_5(n)/\log_5(3)}\\
&=\frac 52Cn^{1/\log_5(3)}\\
&=\frac 52Cn^{\log_5(5)/\log_5(3)}\\
&=\frac 52Cn^{\log_3(5)}
\end{align}
hence $T(n)\in O(n^{\log_3(5)})$, otherwise
\begin{align}
T(n)
&=Cn\sum_{i=0}^{\log_3n} (3/5)^i\\
&\sim \frac 52Cn
\end{align}
hence $T(n)\in O(n)$.